# Does anyone have a Karma launcher for JXBrowser?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, jxbrowser

We would like to run a suite of unit tests that we currently run against Chrome against JXBrowser as well. We launch Chrome via an existing Karma launcher. Interested to hear if anyone has already created a equivilent launcher for JxBrowser so we can run all our tests on both browsers?

Comment: Are you talking about Selenium WebDriver tests?

Comment: No, we use Jasmin and Karma to test our AngularJS app. So Karma is the unit test runner and it uses a bit of code called a Karma launcher to startup the browser to execute the tests. What we want is a launcher especially for JXBrowser.

Comment: As far as I know JxBrowser hasn't been tested with Karma launcher, so it's really hard to say how to make it working. I recommend that you contact JxBrowser support with your request.

Comment: I've got similar problem. I'm gonna to use [karma-script-launcher](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-script-launcher) to run java wrapper for jxbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

I used [karma-script-launcher](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-script-launcher) for this. You just pass path to the shell script as a browser name in the karma configuration.

I wrote sample windows batch script to run simple java wrapper. Java wrapper just creates and shows JFrame with JxBrowser view.

```
public class BrowserWrapper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BrowserPreferences.setChromiumSwitches("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
        Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("JxBrowser");
        jFrame.add(browserView, "Center");
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(800, 600);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        browser.loadURL(args[0]);
    }
}
```